# Powershell LDAP - physicalDeliveryOfficeName not showing up

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

Pretty straight forward question: I'm not sure why the "physicalDeliveryOfficeName" property is not showing up in my output. I've read that it is a non-standard property, but I have not been able to find a way to add it. Everything works perfectly except for the missing "physicalDeliveryOfficeName." Thanks for the help!

```
$Dom = 'LDAP://OU=XX;DC=XX;DC=local'
$Root = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $Dom 
$selector = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$selector.SearchRoot = $root 
$selector.pagesize = 1000
$adobj= $selector.findall() | where {$_.properties.objectcategory -match "CN=Person"} 

(Get-Content c:\FILENAME.txt) | Foreach-Object `
{ `
  foreach ($person in $adobj){ 
  $prop=$person.properties
  if ($prop.cn -like "*" + $_.substring(1, 3) + "*")
    {
     $s1 = $_ -replace $_.substring(0, 4), $prop.cn 
     $s2 = $s1 -replace "AD_DEPT", $prop.department
     $s3 = $s2 -replace "AD_BRANCH", $prop.physicalDeliveryOfficeName 
     add-content C:\FILENAME2.txt $s3
    }
  }
}
```

The AD_DEPT and AD_BRANCH are just placeholders in my original file.

**EDIT**

I read through JPBlanc's answer and did some more research and ended up with this working example. The key seems to be in specifying the properties to load. Thanks!

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectClass=Person)(department=*))"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objOU = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=XX;DC=XX;DC=local")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objOU
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000

$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "OneLevel"

$colProplist = "cn","department","physicaldeliveryofficename"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

remove-item \\SERVER\FTPROOT\FOLDER\FILENAME.MODIFIED
(Get-Content \\SERVER\FTPROOT\FOLDER\FILENAME) | Foreach-Object `
{ `
  foreach ($person in $colResults){ 
  $prop = $person.properties
  if ($prop.cn -like "*" + $_.substring(1, 3) + "*")
    {
     $s1 = $_ -replace $_.substring(0, 4), $prop.cn 
     $s2 = $s1 -replace "AD_DEPT", $prop.department
     $s3 = $s2 -replace "AD_BRANCH", $prop.physicaldeliveryofficename 
     add-content \\SERVER\FTPROOT\FOLDER\FILENAME.MODIFIED $s3
     break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the AD or the QuestAD commandlets?
AD:

Comment: @Tom - This was actually my first time with Powershell, so I'm not familiar with Quest AD. I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: It's worth it. Those cmdlets are pretty straight forward. For example:

AD: get-aduser -Filter * -Properties cn,department,physicaldeliveryofficename

Quest: get-qaduser -includedproperties cn,department,physicaldeliveryofficename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much things have to be said there.

**1. The presence of the attribute**

For an attribute to be queried, it first must be present in the SCHEMA of you directory. SCHEMA defines types and attributes that directory entries can contain. In the schema this attribute has to be defined as "MAY be" or "MUST be " present in a type. For example `objectClass` attribute MUST be present in all types.

If I have a look in the schema of my Windows 2K8 R2, I can see your attribute :

[image]

Now if I use Apache Directory Studio I can see that `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` is present 12 types (11 on a normal server forget SlxAuteur)

[image]

**Conclusion of this first part** : You probably (if you have enough rights) set this attribute on a `user` or an `inetOrgPerson`.

**2. The way you search an attribute**

You'll find here under a sample of usage of a directory searcher. I add the code to modify `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` attribute on a specified user.

```
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://192.168.183.138:389/dc=societe,dc=fr","administrateur@societe.fr","blabla")

# Look for users
$Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$rc = $Rech.filter = "((objectCategory=person))"
$rc = $Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");  
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ipphone");  
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("physicalDeliveryOfficeName"); # Your attribute


$liste = $Rech.findall()
foreach ($usr in $liste) 
{
  # Write-Host $usr.Properties["samaccountname"]
  if ($usr.Properties["samaccountname"] -eq "massin")
  {
    Write-Host $usr.Properties["distinguishedname"]
    $dnUser = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://192.168.183.138:389/$($usr.Properties["distinguishedname"])","administrateur@societe.fr","blabla")
    $dnUser.put("physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "1 rue de la source")
    $res = $dnUser.setinfo()
    $res
  }
}
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Remarks : a Directory search is

1. The node where begin the search
2. the attributes you want (it's not mandatory, but it's a best practice) if you no give them you CAN'T be sure that they are retrieved.
3. The depth (base, onelevel, subtree)
4. The filter

If an attribute is not queried or is empty, it will not be present in the result

Comment: It looks like I was missing the explicit load of the properties I needed. Check out my edit for my working example.